# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - what exactly am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried adjusting this multiple times but I keep getting the ORA-00933. I'm trying to insert values into my table but keep getting an error code. Any thoughts?

```sql
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER
VALUES('Downs', 'Marsha', '555-537-8765', 'Marsha.Downs@somewhere.com');
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER
VALUES('James', 'Richard', '555-537-7654', 'Richard.James@somewhere.com');
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER
VALUES('Frier', 'Liz', '555-537-6543', 'Liz.Frier@somewhere.com');
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerEmail)
VALUES('Trent', 'Miles', 'Miles.Trent@somewhere.com');
```

This is my table:

[image: table]

Adjusted answer:

```
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)

VALUES('Downs', 'Marsha', '555-537-8765', 'Marsha.Downs@somewhere.com');

INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
VALUES('James', 'Richard', '555-537-7654', 'Richard.James@somewhere.com');

INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
VALUES('Frier', 'Liz', '555-537-6543', 'Liz.Frier@somewhere.com');

INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNEREMAIL)
VALUES('Trent', 'Miles', 'Miles.Trent@somewhere.com');
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Could be a client problem. Maybe the command separator isn't  ';' . sqlplus used to have '/' as default, preferable in a new line...

Comment: The error message should tell you **where** the error was found. Sometimes that is helpful. Look around that place (line number and position in the line), it may help you find a mistake. Perhaps you are simply missing a semicolon at the end of one `insert`, or perhaps you misspelled a word, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide a value for every column in the table, in the `VALUES` clause, then you **must** provide a list of column names.

```sql
INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
VALUES('Downs', 'Marsha', '555-537-8765', 'Marsha.Downs@somewhere.com');
```

Alternatively, you could use [INSERT ALL](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-insert-all/)

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
  VALUES('Downs', 'Marsha', '555-537-8765', 'Marsha.Downs@somewhere.com')

  INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
  VALUES('Frier', 'Liz', '555-537-6543', 'Liz.Frier@somewhere.com')

  INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNEREMAIL)
  VALUES('Trent', 'Miles', 'Miles.Trent@somewhere.com')
select * from DUAL
```

Refer to this [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39fb120bc744f3bf603d90110b168e34)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out. I asked my professor and still got no response, so I just randomly decided to submit it row by row like the answer above:

```
    INSERT INTO PET_OWNER (OWNERLASTNAME, OWNERFIRSTNAME, OWNERPHONE, OWNEREMAIL)
VALUES('Downs', 'Marsha', '555-537-8765', 'Marsha.Downs@somewhere.com');
```

and it weirdly worked instead of submitting it all together. Thanks for the support guys!

Comment: What tool are you using to run the commands?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Oracle iAcademy

Comment: Seems like Google hasn't heard of it. Is it a desktop application or a website? Typically the web interfaces don't support scripting.